# How to create a bat that ignores text within brackets and only copies the rest?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

There are many files like this:

```
[2019]Text1(text2).zip
```

I want my batch to copy only Text1, create a folder with that name and move the file in it.

It should be like this: `Text1/[2019]Text1(text2).zip`

This doesn't work, and I don't know how to let it ignore text in brackets.

```
for %%F in (*.zip*.rar) do (
    for /f "tokens=2* delims=%%I in ("%%~nA") do (
    @mkdir "%%F" 2>nul & move "%%I" "%%J\" >nul
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to finish writing your code. The options section of your inner `for` loop doesn't have a closing quote or any specified delimiters even though you're using `tokens=2` (which is correct, btw).

Comment: Thanks for your input and for the remark. Sadly, I still can't manage to make it work the way I want.

Comment: This should work: `for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=](" %%a in ('dir /B *.zip *.rar') do mkdir "%%b" 2>nul & move "%%a]%%b(%%c" "%%b"`

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory & destination directory are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /a-d *.zip *.rar'
 ) DO (
 ECHO filename=%%b
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,* delims=[]()" %%s IN ("%%b") DO (
 ECHO ++%%s++%%t++%%u++%%v++%%w++
 IF "%%w"=="" FOR %%q IN (.rar .zip) DO IF /i "%%q"=="%%v" (
  ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%t" 2>nul
  ECHO MOVE  "%%b" "%destdir%\%%t\" 2>nul
  )
 )
)

POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

After establishing the source and destination directories, use `PUSHD` to switch the current directory to the source directory.

Read each line of a `dir /b /ad` command into `%%b` in turn (basic list without directorynames (`/a-d`) - selecting both all `.zip` and all `.rar` files.

The `echo` line is just to show the filename found. It can be deleted at your whim.

Then examine the string in `%%b`, using delimiters of `[]()`. Assign the first token to `%%s`, the next to `%%t`...remainder of the line to `%%w`

The `echo` line is just to show the way the filename is tokenised - each token is shown between '++'. It can be deleted at your whim.

Using your example filename, `[2019]Text1(text2).zip`, `%%s` should be `2019`, `%%t` Text1, `%%u` `text2`, `%%v` `.zip` and `%%w` should be empty.

If `%%w` is empty, then check that `%%v` is either `.zip` or `.rar`, case-insensitive (`/i`) and if `%%v` matches one or the other, execute a `md` to create the destination directory (if that directory already exists, an error message will be generated which is suppressed by `2>nul`) and the file is then moved to that directory.

Finally, the `popd` returns to the original current directory

**Note** that the `MD` and `MOVE` are merely `echo`ed so that you can see whether the instructions are correct. To actually perform the `MD` and `ECHO` you will need to remove the `echo` keyword from those lines.

The various checks are a reasonably crude attempt to make sure that only files matching `[2019]Text1(text2).zip` will be processed. A file named `[2019]Text1(text2)extra.zip` or `[2019](text2).zip` would fail the checks and not be processed, although `[[2019]]Text1(text2).zip` would pass the checks.

You *could* change the `dir` filemask to eg. `[*]*(*).zip` but even that would pass some non-compliant filenames.

The `move` command will generate a `1 fie(s) moved` message when it washes its socks. You can suppress this message by appending `>nul` to the `move` command.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much!. Your explanations were very informative and helped me a lot. I was researching a bit and found also a handy command to trim the name relative to the input. So I've adjusted it with `folname=!fname:~9,-15!` and it works quite well. Unfortunately, this can also change depending on the actual file.